# Swift Async Await dealing with fallback scenario

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm getting my head around the Async Await functionality and I'm stuck on a fallback scenario involving a feed. In my refactoring a viewModel attempts to get a feed from either the network or if that fails a default fallback.

The problem my head is having is that async await is supposed to remove the nested closure issues, yet I still think it's needed in a fallback use case.

```
func fetch() async throws -> [Feed]? {
    var feed: [Feed]?
    do {
        feed = try await remoteLoader.load()
    } catch {
        // Pass error up the chain for handling
        do {
          feed = try await localLoader.load()
        } catch { 
        // Pass error up the chain for handling
        }
    }
    return feed
}
```

Is this the intended approach for fallbacks?

An alternative that I came up with would be to attempt to load the local first and then replace it with the Remote if that succeeds.

```
func fetch() async throws -> [Feed]? {
    var feed: [Feed]?
    do {
        feed = try await localLoader.load()
        feed = try await remoteLoader.load()
    } catch {
        throw FeedRepositoryError.FetchFeed(error)
    }
    return feed
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either return a non-optional array or an error is thrown.

The function can be reduced to

```
func fetch() async throws -> [Feed] 
{
    do {
        return try await remoteLoader.load()
    } catch {
        return try await localLoader.load()
    }
}
```

If the remote data cannot be loaded the error is being caught and the code tries to load the local data. If this also fails the error is handed over to the caller.

If `remoteLoader` can throw multiple errors add a second catch scope for example if there is an `unavailable` error to fall back

```
func fetch() async throws -> [Feed] 
{
    do {
        return try await remoteLoader.load()
    } catch Loader.unavailable {
        return try await localLoader.load()
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```

You can even omit the second `catch` block if you catch a distinct error in the first one.

Comment: Thanks! So to clarify the localLoader and remoteLoader will throw any errors up to the viewModel and I don't need to handle their specific cases within this method?

Comment: No, the error of the remoteLoader  is handled in the `catch` block. If the remoteLoader throws different errors which are supposed to be passed to the caller you have to add a second catch branch. In this scope rethrow the error.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was struggling with. You do need nested "do catch" blocks to process errors.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Amazing what you forget, the second catch block cleared up the confusion. Marking this as the answer. Thanks +1